# Hierarchical Backlog in Rally

Tags: rally, user-stories, backlog

Is there a way to change the Rally backlog to show a list of stories with sub-stories as a hierarchy?  Right now our backlog makes more sense to just show epic level stories, but it is littered with very granular stories, so it is hard to prioritize at the epic level.  Anyone else have this problem/solution?

Answer (score 0):

Rally's backlog is primarily intended as an area to:

- Prioritize
- and then Schedule

Sprint-sized work products into Iterations. Because Epics aren't schedule-able, they don't show up in the backlog.

You may wish to consider stack-ranking epics from the Plan-User stories page. Or, alternatively, linking your epics to Features in Portfolio Manager, and relative-rank the Feature-linked Epics within the Feature's Story detail screen.